# Match empty list using case/match or if/else?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

Is there any reason that matching an empty list should be done using a case/match instead of if/else, other than style? For example:

```
val a: List

def compute: Int = 
  if (a.isEmpty) 0
  else a.sum
```

versus

```
def compute: Int = 
  a match {
    case Nil => 0
    case _ => a.sum // This is bad. For sake of illustration only.
  }
```

Comment: In this case, `.sum` already has the behavior you want on the empty list, so you could just call it directly.

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon Right. As I said with the `sum` though. That's just an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are just testing empty/not empty then there is little to choose from and `if` is perhaps more meaningful. `match` comes in to play when there are multiple options:

```
a match {
  case Nil => 0
  case hd::Nil => 1
  case hd::tl => 2
}
```

It is also often the case that you can avoid or at least defer this test by using appropriate methods. For example, `take(1)` works on an empty list whereas `head` will fail. And `headOption.map(...)` can be used to safely process the first element, if present.

Comment: So what I'm hearing is that if all I care about is a list's emptiness or non-emptiness, `if` is sufficient. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Tim already has a good answer, but I'd like put a slightly different angle on it.

For lists (or other collections), `.head` and `.tail` are unsafe and `if` makes it easy to accidentally use them in the wrong branch (or to forget to test at all), while `case` avoids need to call these functions.

If your function doesn't need to call them and doesn't need to check more complex conditions, you can as well go with `if`.